# Throw on invalid content-type web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

What is the best way to check incoming content-type of requests in web api?
I have a bunch of controllers, some of them accepts only application/json and others multipart/form-data

I think i need controller attribute like `[AcceptedContentType("application/json")`]

What is the best way to do that? may be ActionFilter?

Comment: You can use the method `OnActionExecuting` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting(v=vs.118).aspx) this method will allow you to take a look at the request object before any action get executed

Comment: you can check the request object at `MessageHandler` and send a response back ... no need of coming this far

Comment: If you need a generic solution - look at this  sample. 1) Controller example: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/ControllerSpecificConfigSample/Controllers/SampleController.cs 2) Configuration attribute example: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/ControllerSpecificConfigSample/CustomControllerConfigAttribute.cs